# Rosmake fails due to CMake issues after upgrade to Groovy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I recently upgraded to groovy and subsequently have had problems building any package what so ever. The error is as follows:

```
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  CMake Error at build/CMakeFiles/CMakeSystem.cmake:1 (INCLUDE):
    include could not find load file:
  
      /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    
  
  
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (include):
    include could not find load file:
  
      /opt/ros/groovy/share/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake
  
  
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init):
    Unknown CMake command "rosbuild_init".
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I removed all of the fuerte packages, so /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake should be missing. Could anyone provide any insight into what is going on and how can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49889/rosmake-fails-due-to-cmake-issues-after-upgrade-to-groovy/) by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem appeared to be that the old fuerte CMake files were still in the directory. Running "rosmake --pre-clean" appears to resolve the immediate issue.

---

Originally posted by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) with karma: 341 on 2012-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1